# Why does Karkaroff speak in English to the Durmstrang students?

Tags: harry-potter, languages

A quote from Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, chapter 16: The Goblet of Fire:

> But this query was answered almost instantly; they were level with the
> Slytherin table now, and Karkaroff had just bustled up to his
> students.
>
> “Back to the ship, then,” he was saying. “Viktor, how are
> you feeling? Did you eat enough? Should I send for some mulled wine
> from the kitchens?”
>
> Harry saw Krum shake his head as he pulled his
> furs back on.
>
> “Professor, I vood like some vine,” said one of the
> other Durmstrang boys hopefully.
>
> “I wasn’t offering it to you,
> Poliakoff,” snapped Karkaroff, his warmly paternal air vanishing in an
> instant. “I notice you have dribbled food all down the front of your
> robes again, disgusting boy —

Harry can obviously understand them so they surely speak English. Poliakoff even has an accent.

But why do they? It makes little sense that they use English when talking to each other.

Comment: Because if they didn't, then Harry (and we) wouldn't be able to understand them.

Comment: Because he's not rude enough to speak Russian in front of guests.

Comment: My guess would be manners. If they had spoken in their native language, it could be seen as being rude, or even hiding something. This is also common for many people as a sign of care and/respect. Ambassadors learn at least a little of another language to show friendship and respect.

Comment: I actually assume that karkaroff is not a native Russian speaker, despite his name, he doesn't speak with an accent and was a death eater which was almost exclusively British in its original incarnation. he at least had been living and acting in britian during voldemorts first emergence, because he was caught, and tried by the ministry of magic, a British organization.

Comment: Easy: They all have universal translators in their comm badges - err - wands, I mean.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Because it would be rude to speak other languages in front of their hosts

Dumbledore makes it clear in his speech that although they may speak different languages, the essence of the Tri-Wizard cup has always been interschool cooperation, not interschool rivalry. The aim is to create a good impression and sitting there gabbling along on in a  foreign tongue is a very poor way to do that:

> ‘Every guest in this Hall,’ said Dumbledore, and his eyes lingered
>   upon the Durmstrang students, ‘will be welcomed back here, at any
>   time, should they wish to come. I say to you all, once again – in the
>   light of Lord Voldemort’s return, we are only as strong as we are
>   united, as weak as we are divided.
>
> ‘Lord Voldemort’s gift for spreading discord and enmity is very great.
>   We can fight it only by showing an equally strong bond of friendship
>   and trust. Differences of habit and language are nothing at all if our
>   aims are identical and our hearts are open.

Karkaroff has clearly spent a considerable time in England before becoming headmaster of Durmstrangs. He would be well aware that conversing in a foreign language in mixed company is a massive [etiquette no-no](http://theclassywoman.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/manners-monday-avoid-speaking-another.html)

---

### Because they may not all speak Russian

It's also mentioned in the text that Durmstrangs is an **international** school. Victor Krum is Bulgarian, Poliakoff is most like a Russian speaker (given his strong accent and stereotypically Russian surname) and Karkaroff/Karkoff/Kirchoff are primarily German or Prussian surnames. At one point, it's noted that Malfoy was considering transferring there and there's no indication whatsoever that he speaks other languages.

**Under the circumstances, it's certainly possible that the only *common tongue* that Krum, Karkaroff and Poliakoff share is English.**

Comment: madam maxime seemed to speak in french to her students, while i dont think we ever hear karkaroff ever speak in russian. And she was far more open to international relations them the Durmstrang crew, so its odd that his reasoning for using english is part of international cooperation.

Comment: French people are notorious for their rudeness.

Comment: ill agree with that, though id also says Russian were too >.< lol.

Comment: @himarm - I'm fairly sure they're renowned for their bluntness (and drunkenness) rather than rudeness.

Comment: :) Give you cover the same idea that it was the common language in your answer, I am withdrawing mine.

Comment: I guess another point is that Karkaroff wanted to show off in front of students from  Hogwarts and Beauxbatons that he had one of the greatest seekers in the world as a student. Speaking  in another language won't get him that kind of attention.